# Is there any router that have plugins in it?

Tags: router, plugins

I wonder why I haven't ever heard of a router that has plugins store in it, this would be pretty much the best way to implement any feature on the device, is this because of security or what?

Comment: You can install additional software on routers running DD-WRT with zero effort.  LibreRouter and DD-WRT list compatible software within the configure pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, like in the WRT54G age (which is a very old device now but the one that started it all), routers have had extremely limited space (4MB, 8MB flash to store bootloader, NVRAM variables, and operating system - if Linux based, this must fit kernel and all support files of a normal Linux system).

This doesn't allow a lot of room for further customization after building a firmware for the device.  4MB devices in particular will barely fit older versions of DD-WRT and newer versions of OpenWRT do not support them.  2MB devices I think can't support any Linux-based custom firmware at all.

That being said, OpenWRT does explicitly support software installation after your main firmware is flashed (using the `opkg` system), and it's possible to add additional modules and software on DD-WRT and systems based on that (`opkg` is fairly easy to get working on any Linux device if there's enough space).

Newer routers are more spacious and include USB ports so this is easier on newer devices.

As far as why manufacturers don't support plugins as a feature on their devices - that's a business decision, not a technical decision.  Most non-technical people don't interact with their routers very much and don't care once it is initially working.